# Rspec test condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am new to using rspec. I am trying to figure out the right test command for these.

```
describe Person do
  let(:person) do
    Person.new({
      first_name: "",
      last_name:  "",
      birthdate:  30.years.ago,
      gender:     ""
    })
  end

  it "is creates a new Person" do
    create(:person).should be_valid
  end

  it "has a full name" do
    person {Person.new(first_name: "", last_name: "")}
    person.should_not be_valid
  end
```

I get the following error: 
Person is creates a new Person FIXED.
Expected pending 'Please test me' to fail. No Error was raised

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, you actually like to check if you can save a record, which you already instantiated before. So why don't you simply call `save!` and expect your code not to return any error? You cannot always rely on `valid?` when you are going to save a record.
My approach would look like

```
expect{ person.save! }.to_not raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
```

Note: `save!` will raise an error, while `save` only returns false

Your second example is similarly imprecise, since you just ask if you record is valid after trying to assign two attributes to it. If it says "No, it is not valid." your test will pass, but it might pass for the wrong reasons. If you call `valid?` ActiveRecord will add errors to the record, if there are any. So why don't you ask for concrete errors here too?

```
person.valid?
expect{ person.errors }.to include("first_name and last_name can't be blank")
```

In that way you really make sure to cause an expected behaviour and your test will not pass if you have another unintentional error.

Answer (score 0):

For the `create` class method you should not pass a Person instance, you should just pass the hash of attributes.

```
describe Person do 
  let(:person_attributes) do 
    { first_name: "", last_name: "", birthdate: 30.years.ago, gender: "" }
  end

  it "is creates a new Person" do 
    create(:person_attributes).should be_valid 
  end
  ...
```

In the second example, if you're not using `let` you should do a straight assignment

```
  it "has a full name" do
    person = Person.new(first_name: "", last_name: "")
    person.should_not be_valid
  end
```